# Late outputs missing for Flink's Session Window

Tags: java, stream, apache-flink, flink-streaming

In my pipeline's setup I cannot see side outputs for Session Window. I'm using Flink 1.9.1

Version 1.
What I have is this:

```
messageStream.
    .keyBy(tradeKeySelector)
    .window(ProcessingTimeSessionWindows.withDynamicGap(new TradeAggregationGapExtractor()))
    .sideOutputLateData(lateTradeMessages)
    .process(new CumulativeTransactionOperator())
    .name("Aggregate Transaction Builder");
```

lateTradeMessages implementes SessionWindowTimeGapExtractor and returns 5 secodns.

Further I have this:

```
messageStream.getSideOutput(lateTradeMessages)
  .keyBy(tradeKeySelector)
  .process(new KeyedProcessFunction<Long, EnrichedMessage, Transaction>() {
     @Override
     public void processElement(EnrichedMessage value, Context ctx, Collector<Transaction> out) throws Exception {
                   System.out.println("Process Late messages For Aggregation");
                   out.collect(new Transaction());
              }
       })
   .name("Process Late messages For Aggregation");
```

The problem is that I never see "Process Late messages For Aggregation" when I'm sending messages with same key that should miss window time.

When Session Window passes and I "immediately" sent a new message for the same key it triggers new Session Window without going into Late SideOutput.

Not sure What I'm doing wrong here.

What I would like to achieve here, is to catch "late events" and try to
reprocess them.

I will appreciate any help.

---

Version 2, after @Dominik Wosiński comment:

```
StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
        env.setRestartStrategy(RestartStrategies.fixedDelayRestart(1000, 1000));
        env.setParallelism(1);
        env.disableOperatorChaining();
        env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime);
        env.getConfig().setAutoWatermarkInterval(1000);


DataStream<RawMessage> rawBusinessTransaction = env
                .addSource(new FlinkKafkaConsumer<>("business",
                        new JSONKeyValueDeserializationSchema(false), properties))
                .map(new KafkaTransactionObjectMapOperator())
                .assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(new AssignerWithPeriodicWatermarks<RawMessage>() {

                    @Nullable
                    @Override
                    public Watermark getCurrentWatermark() {
                        return new Watermark(System.currentTimeMillis());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public long extractTimestamp(RawMessage element, long previousElementTimestamp) {
                        return element.messageCreationTime;
                    }
                })
                .name("Kafka Transaction Raw Data Source.");

messageStream
             .keyBy(tradeKeySelector)
             .window(EventTimeSessionWindows.withDynamicGap(new TradeAggregationGapExtractor()))
             .sideOutputLateData(lateTradeMessages)
             .process(new CumulativeTransactionOperator())
             .name("Aggregate Transaction Builder");
```

Watermarks are progressing, I've checked in Flink's Metrics. The Window operator is execution, but still there are no Late Outputs.

BTW, Kafka topic can be idle, so I have to emit new WaterMarks periodically.

---

Comment: Some basic things to check: do you actually have late events? Are you sure that you can see what ever you print out? Have you tried a simpler window (tumbling) and could you see late events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The watermark approach looks very suspicious to me. Usually, you would output the latest event timestamp at this point.

Just some background information, so that it's easier to understand.

Late events refer to events that come after the watermark processed to a time after the event. Consider the following example:

```
event1 @time 1
event2 @time 2
watermark1 @time 3
event3 @time 1 <-- late event
event4 @time 4
```

Your watermark approach would pretty much render all past events as late events (a bit of tolerance because of the 1s watermark interval). This would also make reprocessing and catchups impossible.

However, you are actually not seeing any late events which is even more surprising to me. Can you double-check your watermark approach, describe your use case, and provide example data? Often times, the implementation is not ideal for the actual use case and it should be solved in a different way.

Comment: Hi, 
you are right. Sorry, I miss understand the "late message" concepts. 
In fact I was never sending "late events" that should match just ended window.

Thank you for your comments and clarification.

The Watermark in my example could be ok though. just wanted to have a "progressing time" when my stream source is idle. But this is different case, not under my consideration for now.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `ProcessingTime` in Your case, this means that the system time is used to measure the flow of the time in the `DataStream`.

For each event, the timestamp assigned to this event is the moment that You receive the data in Your Flink Pipeline. This means that there is no way to have events out-of-order for Flink processing time. Because of that, You will never have late elements for Your windows.

If You switch to `EventTime`, then for proper input data You should be able to see the late elements being passed to side output.

You probably should take look at the [documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.9/dev/event_time.html), where there are various concepts of time in Flink explained.

Comment: Hey, if You want to paste code, please consider editing the original question as it will  be more readable.

Comment: I implemented your suggestions but still it is not working as I would expect.
I updated the original post to include changes.